# SBT: Run test after another project is running in Multi-module project

Tags: build, sbt, multi-module, gatling, integration-testing

I'm trying to run Gatling tests. But it's crucial to have my rest service running. How can I run one project before test in another?

```
lazy val root =
    project.in( file(".") )
      .aggregate("cep", "gatlingTest")

lazy val cep = Project("cep", file("cep"))
    .settings(version := "1.0")......

lazy val gatlingTest = Project("gatlingTest", file("gatling"))
    .enablePlugins(GatlingPlugin)
    .settings(libraryDependencies ++= Seq(.......
```

I was trying to add something like this(dependsOn):

```
lazy val gatlingTest = Project("gatlingTest", file("gatling")).dependsOn(cep)
```

But it's not what I need.

Maybe somehow

```
lazy val gatlingTest = Project("gatlingTest", file("gatling"))
.settings (test in Test <<= test.dependsOn(getProjectRunningTask))
```

where getProjectRunningTask is task to make my service running, but I really don't know how to implement such an idea.

Answer (score 1):

What are you using for running your REST service ? Is it a Spray app using sbt-revolver ?
If that's the case, I guess that :

```
.settings(test in Gatling <<= reStop.dependsOn(test in Gatling).dependsOn(reStart)
```

could be sufficient.
This would mean that you would:

- Start your app in the background using sbt-revolver
- Then start running your Gatling simulations
- And finally stop the server after your tests ran

Comment: Thanks for the initial direction on this, any chance you could flesh out that example a bit more? Does that `.settings` get chained onto the `lazy val root = project in file...` declaration ? Do I need to import `reStop` and `reStart` from Revolver in `build.sbt` ?

I'm interested in accomplishing this same thing, but I'm new to `sbt` and `revolver`.